# My Windows passes validation but still says "Ask for Genuine"

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-genuine-advantage

I have activated my Windows using Product Key. Then In `Computer->Properties` (Win 7 SP1) it says "Ask for Genuine". I followed the steps and validated for genuine successfully using this link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/genuine

But it still says Ask for Genuine.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a non-English Windows install, as "Ask for Genuine" is not something one would see in an English version.  Having said that, can you please post a screen shot of the properties box you're seeing that in?  It's location in the properties page may help us determine what it is exactly you're seeing, so we can help figure it out. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It is English but I will add now the screenshot too.

Comment: @Narek have you tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2008385)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I don't have an error. I pass validation each time. But computer does not understand that I have passed the validation. I have installed fresh copy of Win 7 Pro and have not changed any settings.

Comment: This confusing image was removed in later versions of Windows. It’s normal on Windows 7, though.

Comment: @DanielB **Ask for Genuine** for me too though running a genuine copy in corporate environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Windows activation is actually completely fine! That box that says "ask for genuine Microsoft software" doesn't mean "Your copy of Windows isn't genuine". It simply means "Your copy of Windows *is* genuine, and that's a good thing! You should always use genuine Microsoft software!"

So basically, that box doesn't mean you've done anything wrong or that Windows isn't activated; it's just giving you silly advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think all copies of MS Windows come with those “Ask for Genuine” logos. I have two machines running legitimate copies of Windows but still have those logos. My speculation would be that it is MS's way of encouraging users to use and/or purchase legal copies and not to resort to thievery/piracy.